# Arrows that deal more damage to targets moving towards them and less to targets moving away

Tags: 3d, opengl-es2, combat, godot-3

In real life if you shoot an arrow towards a target that is running towards you.

The targets velocity increases the damage that arrow's velocity would cause.

If the target is moving away from the arrow, they will receive less damage from that same arrow.

More powerful bows shoot their arrows faster, and faster arrows not only do more damage but also travel further

And if you shoot an arrow from a horse, the speed of the running horse increases the velocity of the arrow, thus the arrow does more damage.

But I'm mostly interested to know how to account for the target moving away or towards the arrow without using some tab target system, how would one do that?

And most importantly can it be done using shaders to use less CPU? Because two guys shooting each other isn't that heavy, but a rain of arrows like in the movie the 300 Spartans...well that seems more demanding

Comment: This is not the kind of calculation that would be done on the GPU. If your data is laid out in a nice contiguous array, blitzing through hundreds of arrows impacting each frame is really not a big ask for a modern CPU. But shunting hundreds of arrows to the GPU and shunting the results back CPU-side to drive subsequent gameplay consequences will probably incur more latency just because of the coordination involved. Look to the GPU when your numbers are in the millions (on par with screen pixel counts), or when you don't need to read the results back right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TomTsagk said, your damage value will come from subtracting the velocity of the target from the velocity of the arrow. The new value will have a magnitude equal to your damage.

If the arrow was moving the exact same speed and direction as the target, it will subtract to zero and there will be no damage.

If they were moving the same speed toward each other, it will be twice as much damage as if the target had been standing still.

If the target chased the arrow so fast that they ran into it from behind, there would still be damage, because the magnitude of a vector is always positive. You may need to take care so that the tail of the arrow cannot instantly hit the shooter.

In Godot, there is an easy `.length()` method to automatically calculate the magnitude of a vector. Whether you are using Vector2 or Vector3, it is the same:

```
Vector2 arrowStrike2D = (arrowVelocity2D - targetVelocity2D).length();
Vector3 arrowStrike3D = (arrowVelocity3D - targetVelocity3D).length();
```

That is c#. For GDScript, you would not include the semicolons at the end.

For more helpful methods like `.length()` check out the Vector3 page of the Godot documentation [here.](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html)

Answer (score 1):

#### 2D

In a 2D game if the target is moving away from the arrow, you could do something as simple as take the arrow's velocity, reduce it by the velocity of the target, and use that to calculate damage.

This could look like this (very simplistic example):

```
arrow.velocity = 10; // arrow moves 10 pixels to the right each frame
target.velocity = 6; // target moves 6 pixels to the right each frame

// ...

// at a later point when detecting collisions
impactVelocity = arrow.velocity -target.velocity; // impact velocity would be 4 (10 - 6)
```

So you can then use the `impactVelocity` to calculate damage.

#### 3D

I see you've used the `3D` tag. In that case, you might need to do some more math. You can calculate the target's velocity and direction, then based on how much the target is moving away from the arrow, substract that velocity from the arrow's velocity to calculate damage.

This might be a bit more complex to explain here, as the answer can differ greatly for each project. Following the logic for 2D, you can search online on how to calculate an object's direction based on their velocity, and  create a custom solution that works for your game.

Hopefully this was enough information to help guide you to the next step.